# SQL Query to be used for graphing

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've got a data mining program that is logging viewership data for a large number of video streams. The streams are not up 24/7. The application checks the stats of each stream once every 60 seconds.

What I have is 2 tables, a "data" table which contains columns for a timestamp, the stream name, and the current viewers. A record is only added if the stream is live. The other table is a totals table, it contains a timestamp, total viewership, and the number of streams live.

What I'm looking to do is produce a graph of viewership of a select number of streams over a certain period.

At the moment I've just been doing this to get total:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), "%k:%i") as time, viewers FROM
`tftv_totals` WHERE timestamp BETWEEN <START> and <END>
```

And then if I want individual streams I do this for each stream and combine it manually within excel:

```
SELECT timestamp, viewers FROM `tftv_data` 
WHERE timestamp
    name = <Stream Name>
    BETWEEN <Start> and <End>
```

I'm wondering if there is any way I could produce output something like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| timestamp  | stream1 | stream2 | stream3 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1361962826 | 2       | 3       | 0       |
| 1361962886 | 3       | 4       | 0       |
| 1361962946 | 4       | 8       | 0       |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The point being that stream3 is offline the whole time.

I could do this no problem in PHP, but I was hoping to keep it in SQL for sake of convenience and the hope that there is way to do it that is immensely more efficient than a couple of nested loops.

Comment: Do all the streams have the same timestamps?  I realize you accepted an answer, but I'm guessing that your really want to sample the sterams periodically to account for the fact that the logging may not be consistent across them.

Comment: Yes, the logging is consistent. I create one timestamp at the start of the scrape and use that for all data acquired in that scrape exactly for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    timestamp,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tftv_data.name='stream1' THEN tftfv_data.viewers ELSE 0 END) AS stream1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tftv_data.name='stream2' THEN tftfv_data.viewers ELSE 0 END) AS stream2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN tftv_data.name='stream3' THEN tftfv_data.viewers ELSE 0 END) AS stream3
FROM
    tftv_data
GROUP BY
    timestamp
```

Comment: This seems perfect! Just changed the "THEN 1 ELSE 0" to "THEN tftfv_data.viewers ELSE 0" and it does exactly what I want! Unfortunately it appears I am too new to vote up your reply, but thank you. :)

Comment: Ah, I have now done so. I've been reading posts here for years, it's just the first time I've felt the need to post. If you happen to be remotely interested, here's the output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3205338/betterbrodercc.PNG

Comment: That was a nice chart. Good luck and I am grad to be able to help you